Improving prediction accuracy for Gaussian process with derivative information
I am fitting two different GPs with derivative observations (one with 9 dimensional input and one 12 dimensional input), however for some reason I am getting much worse results for the 12 dimensional case. I originally posted this issue the gpytorch discussion page here.
I have tried the following things, but none improved the results significantly:

use different optimizers (Adam and LBFGS). I get similar results with both optimizers, where the 9D case fits and predicts fine, but the 12D case does not.
use task noises instead of global noise. The function and derivatives should have low noise, so it does not really make a difference if I am using individual task noises or one global noise.
use priors for the hyperparameters (Gamma/Normal prior)
change the kernel - I have tried the RBF and Matern52 kernels
Scale the function observations and derivatives separately, but that also gives worse results for both 9D and 12D. I am also not sure if this makes sense to do since scaling the function has an effect on the derivatives as well.

I am wondering how I should go about troubleshooting what might be going wrong with the modelling because I cannot find anything wrong with the raw data. Any ideas how I can improve the prediction results for the 12D case? Also curious how others scale their input and output/derivative data before model training when using GPs with derivatives.

what happens if you add three useless dimensions to your 9D problem?

@JohnMadden , thanks for the suggestion. I added three redundant dimensions for the inputs as well as for the derivatives (setting them all to 0). I did have to remove the input min-max scaling because otherwise you get division by 0 (as both the min and max of these dims are 0). I still standardize the function values (and scale the derivatives by dividing by the standard deviation). I get the same results for the 9D case. I tried using this code (where only the function values are standardized, but inputs are not scaled prior to training) for the 12D case, but that does not work either.
